# Anaconda Install - Syntax error when opening terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, anaconda

I've recently installed Anaconda on my Mac (MacOS 10.12.6). I have tried both the command-line and GUI installer with the same result.
Anaconda Navigator works fine, is able to create envs, etc. However, when I open my terminal, I see the below error message, and it appears that the conda paths have not been added to my environment as I am unable to call any anaconda-specific commands.

Error when loading terminal:

```
-bash: eval: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 15: `export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(base) ''
```

my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/philippnagel/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/philippnagel/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/philippnagel/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/philippnagel/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I am not sure what could be wrong here. The `.bash_profile` looks like valid syntax to me, but it does not seem to be the file causing the error. The line number referenced does not change when I add lines to the file. Should I be looking somewhere else? Can I get bash to tell me what the offending file is?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me, the solution was adding a newline before the `# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer` line. My `.bash_profile` didn't end in a newline, and this addition messed up the syntax.

But for you, it looks like you already have a couple newlines before that line. Did you by any chance do any reformatting before posting?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think my issue is actually in the bash_profile file directly, it seems to be something conda is doing behind the scenes maybe. I did not do any reformatting. But maybe your answer will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the same error, and i fixed it by changing

```
/Users/philippnagel/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

to

```
~/anaconda3/bin/conda
```